# How to download content from my Django webpage?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a table on one of my Django webpage. I want to give the user the ability to download the content of the table in xl format.
What would be an efficient and good way of doing this?

I was thinking of creating an xlsx file using the xldr library. Writing the data on the file. making the file available for download and then deleting the file at the end, so that my drive stays clean.

but it doesn't feel like a very efficient way.
I'm new in web development, so open to all kind of ideas.
Thanks

Comment: Extra info: the table is being created on the front-end using the data from the db

Comment: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/     i think this might help you you can easily import and export csv xlsx etc just go through the doc.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example in the python doc of [generating a pdf response.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-pdf/#write-your-view) Apart from using `xldr` I don't suppose it needs to be much different, though I haven't done this. It uses `io.BytesIO` in-memory buffering to avoid creating temporary files, and sends that back [using `FileResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.FileResponse) instead of `HttpResponse`